# Adjust div height when window resized to accommodate overflow

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

So I'm trying to make a website with responsive web design, so resizing the page or accessing the website from a handheld device, for example, adjusts the elements according and makes for a nice, clean look.

So far so good, I got a header, nav, logo, and even a video landing to work. My problem is I have two "sidebars" which are essentially two empty `div`and just put a nice 20px wide striped pattern to each side of the main content.

I know to make these display, I have to set everything, including `html, body` with `height:100%;` in my CSS, which worked well until it came time to put content in the middle "content" `div`.

The problem wasn't that they wouldn't display, but the text in my content `div` would overflow if the browser window was resized small enough. When this happened, the two sidebars would not follow the overflow, so you'd get this nice clean look, until you scrolled down to the overflow and saw that the sidebars stopped despite the text still continuing.

I also have a `<footer>` and the text would overflow and continue over and past the footer.

I have tried `min-height:100%;` and `height:auto;` in all of the parent elements, but using them either removes the `height:100%` and as such the sidebars disappear, or doesn't make any difference to the issue.

I would prefer not to `overflow:scroll`, I want to make it so the div resizes to accommodate the overflow, and as a result, pushes the footer down and the sidebars resize to cover the whole page.

In short, it's like I need to set the div to 100% of the document, not 100% of the window.

**My HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<header>
<div class="logo" id="logo"></div>
<?php include("navigation.php"); ?>
</header>
<div id="login" class="login" style="display:none">
<div id="forms" class="forms">LOGIN FORM</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
<div class="sidebarleft"></div><div class="sidebarright"></div>
<div class="top">
<div class="navigationbox">
NAVIGATION TABLE
</div>
<div id="animation">
VIDEO PLAYER TABLE
</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
CONTENT GOES HERE, THIS IS THE CONTENT THAT IS OVERFLOWING
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My CSS:**

```
@-ms-viewport {
    width: device-width;
}

body { 
    font-size: 1.05em;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    background: #4f0100;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top:121px;
    height:100%;
}

html {
    height:100%;
}

header {

    background:url('../images/HeaderPattern.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;

}

.login {
    background:url('../images/GreenPattern.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}

.forms {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4px;
}

#logo{

    left: 0;
    padding-left: 50px;
    color:#edb27a;
    font-family:"Cornet";
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f6d8b6 15%, #e48d40 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size: 4em;
    height: 120px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;

}

nav {

    float: right;
    right:0px;
    padding-right:25px;
    height:120px;
    top:40px;
    position:fixed; 

}

#menu-icon {

    display: hidden;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #edb27a url(../images/menu-icon.png) center;

}

ul {

    list-style: none;

}

li {

    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px

}

.main {
    width:85%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
}

.content {
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:25px;
}

.sidebarleft {
    height:100%;
    width:20px;
    background-image:url('../images/SidebarLeft.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left:-40px
}

.sidebarright {
    height:100%;
    width:20px;
    background-image:url('../images/SidebarRight.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    right:-40px
}

.top {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:320px;
}
```

Comment: Use jquery to set the height of the sidebar by adding the heights of the div. Example, sidebarright height = logo height + top height + content height + footer height. This is just an idea, I haven't tested this.

Comment: Hey Ray, thanks for the suggestion, however I have no knowledge of jquery or any javascript, so I was hoping to do this with pure CSS and HTML. Do you reckon jquery is the only way to do it?

Comment: I couldn't think of a way to do this using pure CSS since the sidebar depends on the height of different divs.

Comment: Is sidebar just a background?

Comment: Yes, sidebar is a repeating 20x20px background. It's an empty div that I want to stretch from the top of the page to the bottom, no matter what, and that includes alongside any overflow, should it occur. Oh and I can't set it as the body background because as I'm trying to make a responsive web page, the content div that the sidebars surround resizes dynamically, so a static body background would look out of place when resizing occurs. Unless I'm missing a trick?

Comment: Well you could also do the whole page with a position:fixed background.  That's if you don't want the background to scroll.  Would also look fine.

Comment: That it would, I may give it a try, I don't think I could scale the background though and have it look the same as what I'm aiming. I think a compromise needs to occur.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted your left/right cols.

See the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sg75uwmv/2/

```
.main {
    width:100%; min-height:100%;
    position:relative; 
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      #606dbc,
      #606dbc 10px,
      #465298 10px,
      #465298 20px
    );
}
.center-col { 
    margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px;  
    background-color:#4f0100;     
}
```

It is the default behavior for the div to scale to fit its content.  So we just have to make sure we don't block that.  Try the background directly on the container (.main), then put another background color into center col.

Comment: Jennifer, thanks for your answer, unfortunately the problem still persisted, when I resized the window down enough that the text overflowed, the div(s) did not scale vertically to allow the stripes to continue to cover the entire page vertically.